# What do mathematicians use to make graphs for analysis textbooks?

Tags: complex-analysis, publishing

Apologies if this is not the correct SE for this.

I have been transferring all of my notes to LaTeX and I have been wanting to include some custom diagrams. I often find my self having to find images to add to my notes but they are not quite what I want. I have tried using different graphic software but nothing seems to do it properly. Could anybody suggest to me any software through which I could make diagrams like this?:

[image]

Comment: Probably fits better on the [TeX SE site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), though I'd like to know the answer myself to be honest. Maybe has something to do with tikzcd or some other similar package?

Comment: Personally, I use $\mathtt{xfig}$, but it's quite old-fashioned and clunky (and needs X Windows, so if you're working on MS Windows you need to install cygwin etc. ...). More or less any software that can produce good encapsulated PostScript or PDF images should work if you use the $\mathtt{graphicx}$ $\LaTeX$ package to include the images.  I think your question will get a better answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I have also posted this to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567000/what-do-mathematicians-use-to-make-graphs-for-analysis-textbooks?noredirect=1#comment1429535_567000. Hopefully we will get a good answer on at least one of the SEs

Comment: I mostly use Geogebra - it's free, has export to tikz/latex, and your figure can be reproduced in a couple of minutes. Any fine tuning is then done in the exported .tex file.

Comment: I have seen simple geometric images drawn in PDFs strictly using LaTeX code.  Dont ask me how, but I do know its done. I have a copy of a .tex file now that does it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a far better fit for https://tex.stackexchange.com/, a site specializing in Tex and LaTeX tips and Q&A's.  And please do not double post a question simultaneously on two or more SE sites.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum r/madlads

Comment: @amWhy the issue is that I do not necessarily want to do my diagrams in LaTeX per say, I want to explore what people are using for diagrams.

Comment: I use Tikz and pgfplots as you can compile the images directly in LaTeX. That way all the fonts in your images/plots match the font of your LaTeX document.

Comment: In Matlab you can also directly export your plots to a TikZ file using [matlab2tikz](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz)

Comment: There's a great article [here](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-2/) which talks about making diagrams exactly like this using inkscape. While it doesn't mention the specifics of inkscape use, the author talks about their setup to take notes in latex efficiently (and making diagrams like this are a part of the process)

Answer (score 5):

One alternative I have used many times is [mathcha.io](https://www.mathcha.io/editor). It lets you create visually and it outputs Tikz ready to include in your document.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest Tikz libraries for Latex, which allows you to draw pretty much anything. It is time consuming to learn (and to draw), but results are fantastic. For instance, you guarantee that the letter type in a figure coincides with that in the body of your notes, something which is not in general true when you use other software. The manual is here http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.pdf

Comment: The reason I don't use *Tikz* libraries is that I prefer to move seamlessly between my *computation* /experimentation and my graphing.  So if I'm computing some sequence, or three-dimensional data, or whatever, and *then* want to visualize it, I can do this entirely within *Mathematica*.  Can't do that with *Tikz*.

Comment: I'd be surprised if anyone is using TikZ on the go while computing or experimenting. I use it only in the last step of finalizing a draft, when I have to replace rough sketches with actual images. I have more control over images with TikZ than with Mathematica, and I don't have to worry if I'm correctly attributing Wolfram in my work.

Comment: Umm... "attributing Wolfram"?  I've never done it.  Please explain.  And could you show one *TikZ* image where you've exploited "more control" than what one has in *Mathematica*?  If you show me one, I'll show you two of the converse.

Answer (score 3):

This image I've made in 6 minutes: 2 minutes of drawing in Geogebra and 4 minutes of fine-tuning the exported TikZ code

[image]

The image itself is much sharper when compiled as a PDF. Various labels like $R$, $I^+$ etc. can easily be added in the .tex file that Geogebra generates for you when you select Export as PGF/TikZ.

TikZ has a bit of a steep learning curve and you'll have to do some googling if you decide to go down this road, but the payoff is huge as you can extremely fine tune your image and seamlessly incorporate any LaTeX code into it that you can think of.

You can try to compile the image yourself with the code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

%arrowhead placement macro, not generated by Geogebra
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
    
%arrowhead placement macro, not generated by Geogebra
\tikzset{-<-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}}}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=stealth,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]

%axes
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-6,0)--(6,0) node[right]{Re $z$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-6)--(0,6) node[above]{Im $z$};

%line segments
\draw [line width=1.2pt,->-=.6] (0.6,0.2)-- (5.,0.2);
\draw [line width=1.2pt,<-=.6] (0.6,-0.2)-- (5.,-0.2);

%small circular arc
\draw [shift={(0.,0.)},line width=1.2pt,-<-=.2]  plot[smooth,domain=0.3217505543966423:5.961434752782944,variable=\t]({1.*0.6324555320336759*cos(\t r)+0.*0.6324555320336759*sin(\t r)},{0.*0.6324555320336759*cos(\t r)+1.*0.6324555320336759*sin(\t r)});

%big circular arc
\draw [shift={(0.,0.)},line width=1.2pt,->-=.2]  plot[smooth,domain=0.039978687123290044:6.243206620056296,variable=\t]({1.*5.0039984012787215*cos(\t r)+0.*5.0039984012787215*sin(\t r)},{0.*5.0039984012787215*cos(\t r)+1.*5.0039984012787215*sin(\t r)});

%big radius
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt,->] (0.,0.)-- (-1.8715470558436564,4.640830918894045);

%small radius
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt,->] (0.,0.)-- (-0.38122376447726786,-0.5046468481995906);

%point x
\draw [color=black] (-1.4,0.)-- ++(-2.5pt,-2.5pt) -- ++(5.0pt,5.0pt) ++(-5.0pt,0) -- ++(5.0pt,-5.0pt) node[below]{$z=-1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use *Mathematica* exclusively, and have published perhaps 1000 figures created with it.  Here's just a start on yours:

[image]

Yes, use *MaTeX* to add *LaTeX* expressions in such figures:

[image]

[Here's a more detailed explanation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85570/drawing-contour-integral-diagrams).

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I have a few questions. I have Mathematica and I am wondering how did you create this image? Is it via code or using a tool? Moreover, can you add LaTeX expressions to a generated image in Mathematica?

Comment: "Never post unsearchable pictures ... instead always typeset using MathJax"

Comment: Your equation $\int x^2 \, dx  = x^3 / 3$ is unsearchable!! Downvoted!

Comment: @terrace:  Geez... You simply do not understand the principle at play here.  NOBODY will ever search for $\int x^2\ dx = x^3/3$.  Do you see why?  That illustration has nothing to do with the essence of the question.  The rule "never post unsearchable pictures..." is for the *POSER* of the question.  The rule is to ensure that a later poser *posting the same or very similar* question will immediately find the prior question.  Don't you see why that is entirely different from the *solver*?  and also different from a required graphical illustration of text in a figure??  I guess not.

Answer (score 2):

#### [`Ipe`](http://ipe.otfried.org/)

[`Ipe`](http://ipe.otfried.org/) is a free drawing editor, easy enough to learn, can produce output with LaTeX/Tikz/PDF/etc., and is pretty powerful. It takes only a minute or two to recreate your diagram. (The arrow heads can even be fine tunes to match those you used, but I'll leave that to you):

[image]